# Is my function prone to under/overflow?

Tags: solidity, security

I don't like using safemath as this is my first conntract and this is getting a bit complicated for me so:

> function withdraw(uint xyz) public {
>
> ```
>     require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= xyz);
>     balanceOf[msg.sender] -= xyz;
>     msg.sender.transfer(xyz);
>     Withdrawal(msg.sender, xyz);
> }
> ```

Basically will "require" do the job here? Can someone send the request from account with 0 causing underflow somehow or not? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically will "require" do the job here? Can someone send the request from account with 0 causing underflow somehow or not? thanks!

Since the require will prevent msg.sender to withdraw any value greater than their balance, then I think yes, the require will do the job for you. It is highly unlikely that `0 - xyz` will occur which will cause the underflow, where `xyz` is any number greater than `0` -which we will assume as the balanceOf[msg.sender] value.

Now with regards to the overflow concern you are using the `.transfer` method which is mostly viewed as safe and a fast way to send eth within a contract though I am not sure if it does prevent overflows from happening even if it is highly unlikely to happen. But if you want to be sure and check maybe you can do `require((msg.sender.balance + xyz) > msg.sender.balance)`